# Optimising writing StringBuilder's content to ServletResponse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, response, stringbuilder, servlet-3.0

I would like to obtain a few comments in regards to optimising my method created for writing of the whole content's of StringBuilder to a ServletResponse.

I did it to avoid creation of gigantic Strings at a single go before passing it to the out.write() method. In my situation a StringBuilder's content length, in some occasions, arrives at few million characters.

```
public static void writeResponse(ServletResponse response, StringBuilder sb) throws IOException {
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        int length = sb.length();
        //to avoid creation of gigantic strings we are writing substrings from the sb 
        int bufferSize = (response.getBufferSize() != 0? response.getBufferSize():10000);
        log.log(Level.INFO, "READY TO SEND To CLIENT, length of responseSB={0}", length);
        if (length <= bufferSize) {
            out.write(sb.toString());
        } else {
            int noWrites = length / bufferSize;
            for (int i = 0; i < noWrites; i++) {
                out.write(sb.substring(i * bufferSize, (i + 1) * bufferSize));
                log.log(Level.INFO, "SENDING To CLIENT, write no={0} of {1}", new Object[]{(i + 1), noWrites});
            }
            int rest = length % bufferSize;
            if (rest != 0) {
                out.write(sb.substring(length - rest, length));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want it to write a single (not chunked) message. Thus, **I would like to know how accurately establish a response's buffer size in relation to a number of characters** (or a String's length) it can fit?

At the moment, I am taking the current buffer size and using it as if it was expressing a number of characters it can fit, how to correctly evaluate the buffer size? Also I am not **including the header size, how could I achieve it**?

I would like to **optimise its performance to maximum (so it works the fastest)**, any suggestion is much appreciated. Or maybe there is all together a better way of writing a gigantic StringBuilder content to ServletResponse?

Comment: I think you shouldn't worry about the buffer size. Let the container do that.

Comment: @mKorbel Glad to see you too. A lot has change, I see, since the last we met. You have gained like 100% more rep. My congrats. Good job. Is it still most of it gathered at `swing` part of SO :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest way is:

```
out.write(sb.toString());
```

If you want to save on memory, replace `StringBuilder` with `PrintWriter` and pass `response.getWriter()` around.

Any optimization regarding buffer sizes will only make things slower. Without optimization, the cost is roughly: `StringBuilder.toString()` + `out.write()` which passed the long string to the container for chunking/sending.

With your optimization, it looks like this: `StringBuilder.toString()` + `substring()` + `out.write()` + copying substring into send buffer + many calls to container to send the pieces.

If you get rid of the builder, the number of calls to the container will stay the same (`out.write()` uses an internal buffer) but you won't waste memory to keep data around.

If you want to keep the `StringBuilder`, then find out how big the pages are and create a `StringBuilder` with a non-default size so it doesn't have to extend it's internal buffer all the time.

Comment: Thanks for your response (+1). I know about the `out.write(sb.toString());` being the fastest, thought, as you say, it is a memory killer. Could you explain what do you mean by: `If you want to save on memory, replace StringBuilder with PrintWriter and pass response.getWriter() around.`? Would you mean by it that to save memory I should write directly to the response?

Comment: Yes. The response will collect the output until the buffer is full. That means: You don't have to keep the data around and the browser will start to receive data before you return from the servlet. And since TCP/IP can't send more than ~1500/8000 bytes of data per packet anyway, the data is going to be chopped up, whether you want it or not.

Comment: Note: Always pass the writer around, never the response object. That way, you can easily test the code in unit tests.

Comment: +1 for passing the writer around. Cut the problem off at the root. Although that will almost certainly send a chunked response.

Comment: Much appreciated again. Very informative answer. Cool, I will give it a go and substitute calls to `StringBuilder.append()` with `PrintWriter.write()`. To be honest I am not using the builder for anything else afterwards.

Comment: @TomAnderson: Well, chunked responses allow the browser to start parsing/rendering while the server is still busy preparing data. It might be slightly slower on the server side but for the user, it's definitely faster.

Comment: Also note that both `Writer` and `StringBuilder` implement the `Appendable` interface, so you could pass an appendable around to further reduce coupling.

Comment: @Jörn Horstmann thanks for this comment. Much appreciated. I didn't notice it at first with this information switching to PrintWriter was straight forward.

Comment: @Tom Anderson I applied your comments I observe performance improvement in this approach versus my initial one. Thanks for that. 
Still I have a slight problem.
I get my Firefox unresponsive for about 5 secs anyway. Why it might be so? May it be that I used gzip on Tomcat to save on message size, thus it must wait for the whole message to arrive, rather than handle it packet at a time or has it something to do with jQuery.getJSON()?

Comment: Who knows? You don't give us any useful details. Maybe there is a bug in Firefox or in your JavaScript to convert the JSON to HTML?

Comment: There are no errors for sure. I checked it. This only happens when I send gigantic messages so it must have something to to with retrieving of the message. If I will think of a question I will post something in a separate thread. I was just wondering if you are aware of some general issues with browsers and large messages? Thanks.

Comment: GZIP compression doesn't need to buffer the entire message; it can compress each chunk separately. However, it's possible that the implementation might do some buffering. Shouldn't be more than a few, or at most a few tens, of kilobytes, though.

Comment: @Boro: Sure. Big message -> slow browser. Browsers don't do magic, yet. With IE6, setting a 2MB `innerHTML` takes 56 seconds even though the browser can load the exact same HTML from a file in less than a second. Get Firebug to see which operation takes how much time.